# Creating scatter plot after getSymbols

Tags: r, quantmod

I get one time-series data using getSymbols as:

```
getSymbols("GM") 
hh=GM[1:10]
```

I try to create a scatter plot for the first two columns:

```
plot(hh[,1],hh[,2])
```

However instead of a scatter plot, I get a time-series chart for the first column.

While trying to use

```
plot.zoo(hh[,1],hh[,2])
```

I got the error **Error in xy[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions**

Finally I have the very stupid way to transfer hh in to vector:

```
h1=drop(coredata(hh[,1]))
h2=drop(coredata(hh[,2]))
plot(h1,h2)
```

It works and I have the scatter chart, but I believe there should be a method to create scatter just using hh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ggplot2 to create a scatterplot (and a many other very easily customizable plots)

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(hh, aes(x=GM.Open, y=GM.High)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks @Roberto, that works. But still not knowing why plot and plot.zoo fail.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question either, but converting the two vectors to numeric makes both plots work as expected. At least this way you don't have to assign them to individual variables.

 `plot(as.numeric(hh[,1]), as.numeric(hh[,2]))`

Answer (score 0):

`plot.zoo` plots only zoo objects (time series charts from zoo objects) ! If you want to make a scatter plot use  `chart.Scatter` from the `PerformanceAnalytics` package.

```
chart.Scatter(GM$GM.Open,GM$GM.High, xlab = “x”, ylab = “y”)
```

ALERT: Leave `xlab` and `ylab` with an empty string or some text, but DO NOT use the default value which is `NULL`. [See my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522143/chart-scatter-in-portfolioanalytics-package-corrupted).